# comparing nullable(of boolean)

Tags: vb.net, nullable

I'm trying to compare two variables of type `nullable(of boolean)` in VB.NET 2010. One of the variables has a value False and the other is Nothing. Now I was expecting the following expression to evaluate to true, but this is not the case:

```
Dim var1 as nullable(of boolean) = False
Dim var2 as nullable(of boolean)
var2 = Nothing

If var1 <> var2 Then
 msgbox "they are different"
End If
```

Why don't I see my MsgBox? How should I compare two nullables (of boolean)?

Comment: The proper way to show message box is MsgBox("they are different")

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [`Nullable.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/213d9ey9?cs-lang=vb):

> Indicates whether two specified `Nullable(Of T)` objects are equal.

```
If Not Nullable.Equals(var1, var2) Then
    MsgBox("they are different")
End If
```

Comment: Ah, much better than the Boolean? non-sense.

Answer (score 5):

This is because in VB.NET

```
Console.WriteLine(False = Nothing)
```

prints `True`.

This has nothing to do with nullability.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that nullable variables have a Value and HasValue property.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/19twx9w9(v=VS.80).aspx

Essentially you'll have to say:

```
If (var1.HasValue And var2.HasValue) And (var1.Value <> var2.Value) Then
      '
End If
```

It's been quite a while since I wrote VB. I'm typically a C# guy. The above concept is right, though.

Comment: This code will not do the job if var1 is null but var2 has a value